# Weird alignment of next badge gear icon on profile page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

This is in Chrome on mac. Reproducible on meta.stackexchange.com, stackoverflow.com, money.stackexchange.com, and probably other SE sites.

The current user activity page `/users/{id}/{name}` has odd placement for the gear icon for next badge (circled below)

[image: current]

The css has...

```css
.svg-icon, .svg-spot {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

If you change the rule to `vertical-align: baseline;`, this particular icon looks better, but the other icons are worse off.

[image]

Could use a css rule targeting this specific icon or update the svg.

Answer (score 2):

I duplicated this, also FF on MAC.

If you look at the CSS and not edit the rule you listed but:

```
.svg-icon {
vertical-align: bottom;
```

into

```
.svg-icon {
vertical-align: baseline;
```

This looks fixed, without the side effects you notice:

[image]

If you look closely now the text starts at the same height. As font sizes are different you won't be able to perfectly align them.